# Are there any .NET API to read SQL Server data pages?

Tags: sql-server, dbcc

I'm writing a C# program and it needs to read SQL Server data pages. Right now what I'm doing is using SQL Server's `DBCC PAGE` command to get this information and then parse the result. When the page number is huge, the performance is not very good. I want to know is there any .NET API that allows me to read SQL Server data pages? I searched around SQL Server's SMO documentation but didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: No. dbcc page is also undocumented.

Comment: Depending on what you need from the data page, you could use the documented [sys.dm_db_page_info DMF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-page-info-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) in SQL 2019 and Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to do you could also look at OrcaMDF from [Mark S. Rasmussen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12469/mark-s-rasmussen)